# Navigate from error to error in laravel.log file using linux less command?

Tags: 20.04

Looking at log errors in my laravel.log is tedious, I use less command to check when somethings goes wrong, I was wondering, is there a way to jump from error to error using keys or shortcut less commands?

Each laravel log error entry starts with a datelike:

```
[2018-01-30 10:51:10] testing.ERROR: Method [middleware] does not exist on
```

So maybe I can use a regex? does less support regex? is this even possible to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

In `less`, press <kbd>/</kbd>; the `:` in the bottom line of the window will turn to `/` . Type `ERROR`, and `less` will highlight all matches. Type <kbd>n</kbd> to jump to the next match, <kbd>N</kbd> to jump to previous match.

Thegeekstuff has a nifty article on the `less` [navigation shortcuts](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/02/unix-less-command-10-tips-for-effective-navigation/).